# Los usuarios no se registran, sale el mensaje de complete los campos cuando ya estan llenos y no se registran

Tags: php, html, mysql, wamp

conexion.php:

```
<?php 
    class clsConexion
    {
        public function conex()
        {
            $server = "localhost";
            $db = "bdrentaapp";
            $usr = "root";
            $pass = "";
    
            try {
                //1-definir la cadena de conexion
                $con_string = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db";
                //2-instanciar el objeto PDO
                $dbh = new PDO($con_string, $usr, $pass);
                echo "Conexion exitosa";
                return $dbh;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error de conexión a la base de datos";
                //muestra el error
                echo $e->getMessage();
                return null;
            }
        }
       

    }

       
?>
```

registrarse.php:

```
<?php 
    class clsConexion
    {
        public function conex()
        {
            $server = "localhost";
            $db = "bdrentaapp";
            $usr = "root";
            $pass = "";
    
            try {
                //1-definir la cadena de conexion
                $con_string = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db";
                //2-instanciar el objeto PDO
                $dbh = new PDO($con_string, $usr, $pass);
                echo "Conexion exitosa";
                return $dbh;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error de conexión a la base de datos";
                //muestra el error
                echo $e->getMessage();
                return null;
            }
        }
       

    }

       
?>
```

registro.php:

```
<?php
include ("model/conexion.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])){

    if (strlen($_POST['cedula']) >= 1 &&
       strlen($_POST['nombre']) >= 1 &&
       strlen($_POST['email']) >= 1 &&
       strlen($_POST['clave']) >= 1) {

        $cedula = trim($_POST['cedula']);
        $nombre = trim($_POST['nombre']);
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
        $clave = trim($_POST['clave']);
        $consulta = "INSERT INTO registro(cedula, nombre, email, clave) VALUES ('$cedula','$nombre','$email','$clave')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        if ($resultado){
            ?>
            <h3 class="ok">!Te has registrado correctamente</h3>
            <?php
        }else{
            ?>
            <h3 class="bad">!Ups ha ocurrido un error</h3>
            <?php
            }
        }else{
            ?>
            <h3 class="bad">!Por favor complete los campos!</h3>
            <?php

        }
}

?>
```

Comment: Tendriamos que ver el HTML o formulario o como lo estes enviando tambien, pues el problema lo tienes enviando los datos, pues no pasa del segundo IF.